# Subject from Dropdown using enum Django

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu, enums, subject

I have ContactForm with subject dropdown using enum, the subject is three different string:
1. I have a question.
2. Help/Support
3. Please give me a call.

When the user send a message have to select one of the above three, here is my code below:

****forms.py****

from django_enumfield import enum

```
class SubjectEnum(enum.Enum):
    subject_one = 'I have a question'
    subject_two = 'Help/Support'
    subject_three = 'Please give me a call'

class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=SubjectEnum.choices(), coerce=str) 
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)




   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And view.py file like belwo:

```
class ContactFormView(FormView):
    form_class = ContactForm
    template_name = "contact/email_form.jade"
    success_url = '/email-sent/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        message = "{name} / {email} said: ".format(
            name=form.cleaned_data.get('name'),
            email=form.cleaned_data.get('email'))
        message += "\n\n{0}".format(form.cleaned_data.get('message'))
        send_mail(
            subject=form.cleaned_data.get('-subject').strip(),
            message=message,
            from_email="enquiries@example.com",
            recipient_list=[settings.LIST_OF_EMAIL_RECIPIENTS],
        )
        return super(ContactFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Contact Form:

```
- extends "base.jade"
- load crispy_forms_tags
    block meta_title
        | Contact Us
    block content
        .jumbotron
            h1 Contact Us
        .row
            .span6
                {% crispy form form.helper %}
```

I get an error say, ValueError: ModelForm has no model class specified. Any idea guys?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify a `Meta` class inside your model form and set the model used. Note that you don't need to specify the form fields that are not different from your model's fields.

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm)
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=SubjectEnum.choices(), coerce=str) 
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'subject', 'message']
```

If you don't have a model `Contact`, you should be using a `Form` instead of a `ModelForm`:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=SubjectEnum.choices(), coerce=str) 
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

[See the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) for more information on `ModelForm`s and their use.